# Wronskian is independent to the choice of a basis

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

How to show that the Wronskian is independent to the choice of a basis of $V$? Let $f_1(x), \ldots, f_n(x)$ be a basis of a vector space $V$. Then the Wronskian is the determinant of a matrix whose i-th row is $f_1^{(i-1)}, \ldots, f_n^{(i-1)}$. Here $f_j^{(i)}$ is the i-th derivative of $f_j$. Thank you very much.

Comment: What do you mean by $f_1(x),\ldots,f_n(x)$ is a basis of $V$? And in which space is $x$?

Comment: The statement in the title is false. If $n=1$ and  $V$ is the space of all multiples of $f_1(x)$ then any  $\lambda f_1(x)$, $\lambda\ne0$, is a basis of $V$, but the corresponding Wronskians $W_\lambda(x)=\lambda f_1(x)$ do not agree.

Comment: Maybe OP meant the orthonormal basis?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As stated in the comments, the Wronskian is **not** independent of basis, but it is determined up to a constant.

If $g_1(x),\dots,g_n(x)$ is a basis, then $g_i(x) = \sum_{j=1}^n c_{ij}f_j(x)$ for some constants $c_{ij}$ (since $f$'s form a basis). Let ${\bf f} = [f_1(x)\;f_2(x)\; \cdots \;f_n(x)]^T$, ${\bf g} = [g_1(x)\;g_2(x)\; \cdots \;g_n(x)]^T$, and $C = (c_{ij})_{n \times n}$. Then ${\bf g} = C{\bf f}$. Therefore, ${\bf g'} = C{\bf f'}$ (because $C$ is constant) and in general ${\bf g}^{(k)} = C{\bf f}^{(k)}$. Thus $[{\bf g} \; {\bf g}' \; \cdots \; {\bf g}^{(n-1)}] = 
[C{\bf f} \; C{\bf f}' \; \cdots \; C{\bf f}^{(n-1)}] = C[{\bf f} \; {\bf f}' \; \cdots \; {\bf f}^{(n-1)}]$. Therefore the Wronskian of the $g$'s is $\mathrm{det}(C)$ times the Wronskian of the $f$'s. [Also, since the $g$'s form a basis this determinant is a non-zero constant.]